# I am given a ledger. I want to know how many days it took every bills to gets settled

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I am given a ledger. I want to know how many days it took every bills to gets settled.

I am running two loops. One for every bill and another for adding all the settled amounts. If the amounts just match, I want to copy the last date of the last payment to calculate the gap between billing date and settlement date.

```
Credit = 0 Balance = 0 
for i in range(len(df.VOUCHER_NO)):
   for j in range(len(df.VOUCHER_NO)): 
       if df.DEBIT[i] + Balance < Credit:
           Credit = Credit + df.CREDIT[j]
           df.CREDIT[j] = 0
           df.Date[i] = ''
       else:
           df.Date[i] = df.DOC_DATE[j]
       Balance = Balance + df.DEBIT[i] - Credit
```

But it is copying some date date that I don't understand.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect in your `df.VOUCHER_NO`, Date was initialized as date. When in your loop you put `df.Date[j]=''`, it will consider that you are you are initializing date to the beginning of the *EPOCH* which is `1970-01-01 00:00:00`
Read this doc for better understanding of date in python : https://www.javatpoint.com/python-epoch-to-datetime

Comment: I have taken out date conversion. Even if I copy just the data and then convert, my code does not seem to work. Not able to figure out what I am doing wrong with the loops/conditions.

Comment: Show the definition of **df** . if **df.Date** is of type **datetime** then it is not a good idea to initialize it as **df.Date[i]=''** . I would suggest you to use something like **df.Date[i]=None**